# Which query should I use to get the age at which each movie star starred in movie for the first time?

Tags: sql

This is the Data base schema:

[image]

Which query returns the age at which each movie star starred in a movie for the first time? Stars for whom there's no information whether they've been in any movies should not be listed.

```
A: SELECT NAME, MIN(MOVIEYEAR) - YEAR(BIRTHDATE) AS DEBUT_AGE
   FROM MOVIESTAR
   NATURAL JOIN STARSIN ON NAME = STARNAME
   GROUP BY NAME;

B: SELECT NAME, MIN(MOVIEYEAR - YEAR(BIRTHDATE)) AS DEBUT_AGE
   FROM STARSIN
   JOIN MOVIESTAR ON STARNAME = NAME
   GROUP BY NAME;

C: SELECT NAME, MOVIEYEAR - YEAR(BIRTHDATE) AS DEBUT_AGE
   FROM MOVIESTAR
   LEFT JOIN STARSIN ON NAME = STARNAME
   WHERE MOVIEYEAR IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY NAME
   HAVING MIN(MOVIEYEAR);

D: SELECT DISTINCT MS.NAME, MOVIEYEAR - YEAR(BIRTHDATE) AS DEBUT_AGE
   FROM MOVIESTAR MS, STARSIN
   HAVING MS.NAME = STARNAME
          AND MOVIEYEAR <= ALL (SELECT MOVIEYEAR
                                FROM STARSIN SI
                                WHERE SI.STARNAME = MS.NAME);
```

I know that `D` is not the answer because we can't have `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`. But I don't know which of the other three is the right one. I'd appreciate an explanation what each query does.

Comment: It would be nice if you create http://sqlfiddle.com/ for your issue.

Comment: Is this a homework question, Daniel?

Comment: No, it's an exam preparation question.